# How to use a custom function in a join clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, function, t-sql, inner-join

I have a problem with the following statement :

```
SELECT
      B.idimpianto, 
      B.CodiceImpianto, 
      B.DescrizioneImpianto,
      B.CodiceCDC, 
      B.descrizioneCDC
FROM ITCOWBase.dbo.GetImpiantiUtente(B.idimpianto) AS A 
INNER JOIN dbo.vImpianti AS B ON A.idimpianto = B.idimpianto
```

When I try to execute it, the SQL parser says:

> the multipart identifier B.impianto could not be bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `apply`:

```
SELECT     B.idimpianto, B.CodiceImpianto, B.DescrizioneImpianto,
           B.CodiceCDC, B.descrizioneCDC
FROM dbo.vImpianti b cross apply
     ITCOWBase.dbo.GetImpiantiUtente(B.idimpianto)
```

It looks like you are only doing filtering, so you want `cross apply` rather than `outer apply`.